# Изменить кодировку принимаемого json файла с сервера, в приложении на UTF-8

Tags: java, json, android-studio, utf-8, app

В приложение грузятся данные из .json файла расположенного у меня на хостинге. Всё работает правильно, кроме кодировки. Русский текст, не распознает, и в приложении отображается как на фото:

[image]
Я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы в приложении он преобразовывался в utf-8 кодировку. Куда и что нужно дописать ? вставить?

Помогите пожалуйста, я не очень силён в java.. заранее благодарен.

код из класса:

```
public class Config {

public static final String CLIENT_ID = "10c7cb1226ea5ef2f1241637221b8054";
public static final String USER_ID = "217869219";
public static final String URL = "http://webhost.com/list.json";
public static final String APP_SHARE_URL ="https://www.dropbox.com/s/mn/Radio.apk";}
```

Еще один класс:

```
public class UtilFunctions {
static String LOG_CLASS = "UtilFunctions";

/**
 * Check if service is running or not
 * @param serviceName
 * @param context
 * @return
 */

public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceName, Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for(RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if(serviceName.equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static ArrayList<Track.TrackDetails> getSongsList(){

    ArrayList<Track.TrackDetails> mArrTrackList = new ArrayList<Track.TrackDetails>();
    if(PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST!=null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.size(); i++) {
            if (PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(i).getGenre().equalsIgnoreCase(PlayerConstants.CATEGORY)) {
                mArrTrackList.add(PlayerConstants.SONGS_LIST.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return mArrTrackList;
}


/**
 * Read the songs present in external storage
 * @param context
 * @return
 */



public static Track jsonParesing(Context context,String response) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Track mObjTrack = new Track();
    ArrayList<Track.TrackDetails> mArrAllTrackDetails = new ArrayList<Track.TrackDetails>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            Track.TrackDetails trackDetails = new Track.TrackDetails();
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            trackDetails.setId(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_id)));
            trackDetails.setTitle(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_title)));
            trackDetails.setUser_id(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_user_id)));
            trackDetails.setLabel_name(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_label_name)));
            trackDetails.setGenre(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_genre)));
            trackDetails.setDescription(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_description)));
            trackDetails.setDownloadable(jsonObject.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.key_downloadable)));
            trackDetails.setStreamable(jsonObject.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.key_streamable)));
            if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_tag_list)) != null) {
                trackDetails.setTag_list(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_tag_list)));
            }
            if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_duration)) != null) {
                trackDetails.setDuration(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_duration)));
            }
            if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_created_at)) != null) {
                trackDetails.setCreated_at(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_created_at)));
            }
            if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_permalink_url)) != null) {
                trackDetails.setPermalink_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_permalink_url)));
            }
            if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_artwork_url)) != null) {
                trackDetails.setArtwork_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_artwork_url)));
            }
            if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_stream_url)) != null) {
                trackDetails.setStream_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_stream_url)));
            }
            if (!jsonObject.isNull(context.getString(R.string.key_download_url))) {
                if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_download_url)) != null) {
                    trackDetails.setDownload_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_download_url)));
                }
            }
            mArrAllTrackDetails.add(trackDetails);
        }
        mObjTrack.setTrackDetails(mArrAllTrackDetails);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PlayerConstants.OBJ_TRACK = mObjTrack;
    return mObjTrack;
}

/**
 * Get the album image from albumId
 * @param context
 * @param album_id
 * @return
 */
public static Bitmap getAlbumart(Context context,Long album_id){
    Bitmap bm = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    try{
        final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        if (pfd != null){
            FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd, null, options);
            pfd = null;
            fd = null;
        }
    } catch(Error ee){}
    catch (Exception e) {}
    return bm;
}

/**
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
/**
 * Convert milliseconds into time hh:mm:ss
 * @param milliseconds
 * @return time in String
 */
public static String getDuration(long milliseconds) {
    long sec = (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
    long min = (milliseconds / (60 * 1000))%60;
    long hour = milliseconds / (60 * 60 * 1000);

    String s = (sec < 10) ? "0" + sec : "" + sec;
    String m = (min < 10) ? "0" + min : "" + min;
    String h = "" + hour;

    String time = "";
    if(hour > 0) {
        time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    } else {
        time = m + ":" + s;
    }
    return time;
}

public static boolean currentVersionSupportBigNotification() {
    int sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdkVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls() {
    int sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdkVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}}

    PlayerConstants.OBJ_TRACK = mObjTrack;
    return mObjTrack;}
```

**это конфиг (путь к файлу .json на хостинге)**

```
package com.online.radio.util;
public class Config {

    public static final String CLIENT_ID = "10c7cb1226ea5ef2f1241637221b8054";
    public static final String USER_ID = "123456789";
    public static final String API_URL = "https://api.cloud.com";
    public static final String URL = "http://webhostapp.com/json/index.json";
    public static final String APP_SHARE_URL ="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onlineradio.apk";


}
```

**---------------------------**

```
public static Track jsonParesing(Context context,String response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Track mObjTrack = new Track();
        ArrayList<Track.TrackDetails> mArrAllTrackDetails = new ArrayList<Track.TrackDetails>();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                Track.TrackDetails trackDetails = new Track.TrackDetails();
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                trackDetails.setId(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_id)));
                trackDetails.setTitle(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_title)));
                trackDetails.setUser_id(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_user_id)));
                trackDetails.setLabel_name(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_label_name)));
                trackDetails.setGenre(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_genre)));
                trackDetails.setDescription(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_description)));
                trackDetails.setDownloadable(jsonObject.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.key_downloadable)));
                trackDetails.setStreamable(jsonObject.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.key_streamable)));
                if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_tag_list)) != null) {
                    trackDetails.setTag_list(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_tag_list)));
                }
                if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_duration)) != null) {
                    trackDetails.setDuration(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_duration)));
                }
                if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_created_at)) != null) {
                    trackDetails.setCreated_at(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_created_at)));
                }
                if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_permalink_url)) != null) {
                    trackDetails.setPermalink_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_permalink_url)));
                }
                if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_artwork_url)) != null) {
                    trackDetails.setArtwork_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_artwork_url)));
                }
                if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_stream_url)) != null) {
                    trackDetails.setStream_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_stream_url)));
                }
                if (!jsonObject.isNull(context.getString(R.string.key_download_url))) {
                    if (jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_download_url)) != null) {
                        trackDetails.setDownload_url(jsonObject.getString(context.getString(R.string.key_download_url)));
                    }
                }
                mArrAllTrackDetails.add(trackDetails);
            }
            mObjTrack.setTrackDetails(mArrAllTrackDetails);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("myLog", response);
        }
        PlayerConstants.OBJ_TRACK = mObjTrack;
        return mObjTrack;
    }
```

Comment: Пальцем покажите где у вас строчка, загружающая Ваш json с Вашего хостинга

Comment: Может просто ваш JSON файл не в utf8? Потому в моих приложениях данные с сервера идут сразу в utf8 и никаких проблем с русскими буквами не возникает. Предоставьте, пожалуйста, образец файла, причем именно файлом, а не вставленным текстом

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, ссылка к файлу
(tequila.000webhostapp.com/json/index.json)

Comment: Где же она? Вы наверное вставить забыли

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, я через notepad++ сохранял и кодировал в utf-8  и в utf-8 без BOM . и всё равно в приложении отображается текст иероглифами всякими...

Comment: Попробуйте вывести текст ответа в логи и посмотреть как там с кодировкой. `Log.d("myLog", response);`

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, 
05-05 08:27:22.116 21739-21739/com.online.radio W/System.err: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Ð ÐµÐ¿

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, там вместо Ð ÐµÐ¿ - должно быть написано Реп... если верить логам.. и если я конечно в правильное место вставил этот Log.d.
-------------
05-05 08:32:44.032 21739-21739/com.online.radio D/com.online.radio.activity.HomeActivity: title : Ð ÐµÐ¿

Comment: С файлом все впорядке. Значит данные неверно перекодирует мы при получении. Добавьте, пожалуйста код обращения к серверу, откуда, собственно, берется response

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, не совсем понял что куда добавить... ((

Comment: Добавить в ваш вопрос. Вопросы можно редактировать. А добавить нужно тот код, который обращается к серверу и получает содержимое файла.

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко, добавил

Comment: Так этот код у вас уже есть. Он не производит обращения к серверу. А только лишь обрабатывает результаты обращения. Откуда вызывается эта функция? Скорее там и производится запрос к серверу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58236/discussion-between--and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

помогли найти ответ на https://stackoverflow.com/a/38932551

Нужно добавить строчку кода (тот что ниже) в метод **jsonParesing** в классе **UtilFunctions.java**

```
newStr = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(oldStr, "iso8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

перед

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
```

импортируем класс **URLDecoder** (Alt+Enter),

для **newStr** делаем **RenameReference** в **response** (Alt+Enter)

для **oldStr** делаем **RenameReference** в **response** (Alt+Enter)

и следом делаем **Add 'catch' clause(s)** (Alt+Enter)

в итоге, строчка должна иметь вид:

```
response = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(response, "iso8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

---

отдельное спасибо **@НикитаВасильченко** за помощь!

p.s: и извиняюсь если я объяснил всё, как "эстонец"..